# How to customize Cyanogenmod Source?

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I am trying to build my own Android ROM. 
I have synced the Cyanogenmod KitKat repo, and i am wondering what I have to edit to change the SystemUI. 
Could someone help me out?? I have no idea where to start
Tia, Caelin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning on modifying SystemUI, you can find that package in

```
frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/
```

You'll find much of the, well, UI of the system here. It is essentially just another Android app, albeit a very important one. You can find the layouts and source here to make the modifications you're looking for to SystemUI.

Comment: So is that where I can change stuff like the looks of 'Settings' or the way my notification bar looks?? @mattgmg1990

Comment: The notification bar is in SystemUI. The settings screens will be found in `packages/apps/Settings`